# Google just charged me for my in-app Test purchase, What do I do?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

My app is in alpha mode but published. I can see this in developer console 
"Only alpha and beta testers can see the listing in Google Play, since you have not yet uploaded any APKs to prod."

But when I tested a in-app purchase with a different test account, My credit card was charged.

First how do I get My money back.
Second how test in-app properly, without been charged.

Tharks

Comment: Looks like its cancelled in google wallet, but my Bank account has the entries

Answer (score 46):

This happened to me as well. This is because the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) says :

> It’s easy to set up test purchases—any user account can be chosen to
>   be a test account, and any user of a test account can make test
>   purchases with any available payment method (even though there’s no
>   charge to the payment method).

But I missed this part :

> Next, create license test accounts for authorized users. In the
>   Developer Console, go to Settings > Account details, then in the
>   License Testing section, add the addresses to Gmail accounts with
>   testing access field.

So having a test account that opted-in to the alpha release isn't enough, you need to add the same email address to the licensing section.

If you don't see this message, you will be charged :

[image: This is a test order, you will not be charged.]

Comment: what a mess... but your answer solved my issue in no time, +1 thanks!

Comment: +1 Thanks man. First I wondered why it wants me to add a credit card, but it works after I added it as test account.

Answer (score 2):

For `First how do I get My money back`, you can also go into the Play Console, Order Management, and issue your test user a refund.

Then be sure to add the test user(s) to the list of license testers as in @z0me's answer to prevent it happening again.

Answer (score 0):

When purchases are complete, Google Play prevents the orders from going to financial processing, ensuring that there are no actual charges to user accounts, and automatically canceling the completed orders after 14 days.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Everything is in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid being charged by Google, you need to create a Google group with all your beta testers. Then add the id of the group to the Google play console. When any of the developers within that group try to purchase an IAB item, your app will prompt a message saying that they will not be charged because the transaction is a test.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me - I was charged for the test purchases too (( After reading https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html I see that it's possible to make real purchases when testing IAB (seems it happens by default), but for not-charging purchases:

> Note: For test purchases, leave the orderId field blank. You can use the purchaseToken field to identify test purchases.

Now I need to find out where's that `orderId` - I do not see it in dev console or in Google IabHelper class I'm using...

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Setting** **Manage tester** and add your google account email id which you used in Google play store app purchase then Google don't charge you.